# Why does SqlConnection.Open() trigger a "Cannot enlarge memory arrays" error in a Unity WebGL application

Tags: sql-server, unity-game-engine, out-of-memory, unity-webgl

I have a very simple Unity WebGL project that I am trying to connect to a SQL Server database from.

When I run the project in the Editor, it works fine.

When I run the WebGL build, as soon as I try to open the DB connection I get an "Out of memory" pop-up and this error in the console:

> PrototypeProject.loader.js:1 Cannot enlarge memory arrays. Either (1)
> compile with  -s TOTAL_MEMORY=X  with X higher than the current value
> 2144141312, (2) compile with  -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1  which allows
> increasing the size at runtime, or (3) if you want malloc to return
> NULL (0) instead of this abort, compile with  -s ABORTING_MALLOC=0

My understanding is that the advice included in the error is out of date because allow memory growth defaults to enabled and there is no total memory setting in recent versions of Unity.  I can't see why (3) would be a sensible thing to do

I know the problem is triggered (every time) by connection.Open because the first of these debug lines is output but the second is not

```
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);     
    Debug.Log("Calling connection.open");
    connection.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Connection open");
```

One option would be to stop trying to connect to the database directly and call a web service which does the database work instead.  Yes, I know that having a three-tiered architecture is a better design in any case - this was approach was used in a (failed, clearly) effort to prototype something quickly

However I really want to understand what's going on here in case I might have similar issues in future.  I know that SOMETHING has to be the tipping point that runs you out of memory, but just opening a connection doesn't intuitively (but maybe I'm wrong...) seem like it should be a massive memory hog and I can't see any noticeable difference when using the Profiler in the editor

Does anyone have any experience in troubleshooting SQL Server connections in particular, or memory issues in general, in WebGL that might be relevant to understanding and avoiding this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was much more rudimentary than I expected - it's just not possible to use SqlConnection in a WebGL build because SqlConnection in turn is trying to use Sockets that WebGL builds do not have access to

Exactly why this manifests as an "out of memory" error, or why the Unity Editor couldn't be a little bit more helpful and warn you that you are using classes that are not going to work when you start a WebGL build, I do not yet understand...

Comment: WebGL has a lot of quirks.. such as unity lets you use WCF services in the editor setup for webgl, in fact it even compiles, just barfs at runtime because it cant use it..  tbh you really want to give the world direct access to your sql server with some element of knowing the connection details are in the app? an interface webpage to run and return data is often normal for this